# Can't connect to 5ghz wifi

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, and I've recently upgraded my wireless card to a Aukey WF-R15 Dual-Band Wireless PCI-E adapter so that I can connect to 5Ghz wifi.  Unfortunately I've been unable to connect to the 5 Ghz wifi, but I have been able to connect to the 2.4 Ghz signal.  My other devices can connect to the 5 Ghz signal, so it's something with my computer.

**Edit:**

Output of `sudo iwlist scan`

```
wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Channel 153 : 5.765 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Comment: Does your hardware and driver combination support 5 gHz channels? Verify: `iwlist channel`

Comment: I believe so, I ran that command, and here's part of the output.  It's too long to submit everything it posted, but here was one line:


          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz


lo        no frequency information.

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

Comment: And is the router in question on channel 56? Does the wireless adapter see the router with: `sudo iwlist scan`? If you have results that are too long to post, paste them here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: No, it's not on channel 56.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25447154/

Comment: The point is, is the router on a channel that the wireless adapter does? For example, I can put my router on channel  153; however, my laptop wireless adapter is not capable of 153. Is it set to a fixed channel or Auto. A fixed channel is preferred.

Comment: Please [edit] the output of `lspci -vvk` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result? I know it may seem a bit overwhelming for a novice but your info so far is a bit vague and the diagnostics will likely cover all options that may cause your issue. Thanks.